# Cron job not running at specified time

Tags: cron

My date command -

```
May 19 20:28:00
```

Crontab file -

```
ubuntu@ip:/etc/cron.daily$ crontab -l
24 20 19 5 1 /opt/sw/p3/scratch/test.py > /opt/sw/p3/scratch/test1.txt
```

Based on the above command and date, My job should have run at 20:24 on May 19 but I dont see any output in my test1.txt

test.py just prints a statement -

```
print "I will be run soon"
```

Why my crontab job did not run at that time?

Comment: Have a look at the file permissions, maybe the file cant be executed? Have you had a look at your syslog logs?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running this cron job on a remote server, please verify whether the server's timezone is same as your's. If not you can change the server default timezone and try setting the cron job again to a different date/time.